# How do I make movement smooth when user holds down key in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a game and the movement when I press keys isn't very smooth and I'm having difficulties fixing it.
I want the user to be able to hold the key down without it hesitating

```
primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key) -> {

        if(key.getCode()==KeyCode.W){
            objOne.setLayoutY(objOne.getLayoutY() -  10);
        }
      //other keys

   }
```

Anyone have any tips on making it smooth?

Comment: There's is different and didn't work with what im doing.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something about your question, the concept is the same. What about the linked question doesn't work for you?

Comment: I'd try moving 1 instead of 10.

Comment: moving 1 instead of 10 just reduces the speed. They're overriding method and using an new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() while I'm not overriding the method and am doing it with addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key). Their way should work partly, but I don't think the animation timer will work for this. Ill try it, but it'll probably be a waste of time

Comment: After trying it, it make the rectangle not move at all.

Comment: The "hesitating" that you're seeing is, I believe, caused by the operating system. There is a delay before the key is considered to be pressed-and-held rather than just pressed. That's why using the `AnimationTimer` helps. You update various state in the `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` handlers but it's the `AnimationTimer` that updates the position of the `Node` based on said state. Since `AnimationTimer.handle` is called every frame it is not subject to the delay. It also allows you to handle more than one key being pressed at once (which may not be possible with just handlers).

Comment: I just implemented an `AnimationTimer` in my code in Windows 10, and the initial hestations -- as well as "hiccups" during the press -- are still happening.

Comment: @ksnortum See [this example](https://gist.github.com/tkslaw/d9859c34e25accf5226aaf1844ad24cc). It is very similar to the example James_D gives in his answer to the duplicate. I tried it on Windows 10 and there is no hesitation. Any hiccups experienced look to be caused by rendering delays, as the movement is dependent on the FPS.